# Make a table based on the value of a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am stuck in a part where i am trying to fetch the data from php file to the script in json format . I am new to php just trying to learn from w3schools and i got stuck in  HTTP method POST to send data to the PHP file and display in html but i am getting an error as

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

And here is my code which i had done till now in front part i used html and javascript as :

```js
<script>
function change_myselect(sel) {
  var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
  obj = { "table":sel, "limit":20 };
  dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      txt += "<table border='1'>"
      for (x in myObj) {
        txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].name + "</td></tr>";
      }
      txt += "</table>"        
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "get_email.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
}
</script>
```

```html
<select id="get_email" name="get_email" onchange="change_myselect(this.value)">
<option value="">Choose an option:</option>
<option value="3">Customers</option>
<option value="4">Products</option>
<option value="5">Suppliers</option>
</select>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

And here is my php file :

```
<?php
  include("admin/include/config.php");
  $id=$_POST['get_email']
  if(isset($_POST['$id'])){
  $sql=mysql_query("select * from subscription where id=".$id);  

   $returnArray = array();
   while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $returnArray = 
    array("email"=>$row['email'],"creationDate"=>$row['creationDate']);  
     }

    // return JSON response.
     header('Content-Type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($returnArray);
         }
```

Can you suggest me what i am doing wrong in the above script . Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe try changing `myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);` to `myObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I am still getting an same error after updating it also

Comment: You have a wrong json format. I think it should be `obj = {  
   "table":"sel",
   "limit":20
}` - added `""` around `sel` which is a string.

Comment: I have updated my php file please check i am not sending the data in json format but still i am getting an same error

Comment: I am just trying to  achive something like this but from my database  https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_html_table_dynamic

Comment: Have you tried changing `echo json_encode($returnArray);` to `echo json_encode($returnArray, true);` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150075/discussion-between-piyush-seofaceup-and-antonis-tsimourtos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've some error in PHP code, you're just printing the email. That's not a JSON string.

Read this to know more about JSON: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

By reading your JS code you're accessing name from the object, so may need to change the PHP script as follow,

```
<?php
  include("admin/include/config.php");
  $id=$_POST['get_email']
  if(isset($_POST['$id'])){
  $sql=mysql_query("select * from subscription where id=".$id);  // You missed semi colon here.

  $returnArray = array();
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     $returnArray = array("email"=>$row['email'],"name"=>$row['name']); // assuming column name exists.      
 }

// return JSON response.
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($returnArray);
}
```

Comment: Yes now i had printing the data in json format but still same problem

Comment: I am just trying to  achive something like this but from my database  https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_html_table_dynamic

Comment: I am getting undefined index get_email

Comment: That's because you're not sending the email id from XHR request properly.